# Securing JAAS config file

Tags: java, jaas

I'm developing a Java application which is run in Windows domain environment. 
To authenticate users I'm using Krb5LoginModule available in JAAS.
JAAS Login Configuration File (let's call it jaas.conf) is embedded in application jar, which is stored on network share (read-only access).

Now every user can copy the application jar to his local disk, edit jaas.conf, and set his own LoginModule which would allow him to act as different user.

Is there any way to prevent this? How to secure the application?

Comment: 'Every user' can only do that if he has the JAR tool installed. Signing the JAR might be the answer.

Comment: JAR tool is not necessary. Any zip/unzip tool can open jar files. Signing may be the answer, but a bit annoying. Any other possibilities?

Answer (score -2):

Usr e Pwd must be provided by user. You have to call your own login interface where the user can provide username and password. Why you want put the usr&pwd into the jaas.conf?

Anyway, if you want to lock the usr&pwd you can

1. use certificate
2. crypt into the file
3. write into a code

Comment: He hasn't said anything about putting passwords into the JAAS configuration file. Your first suggestion isn't compatible with Kerberos. 'Write into a code' is meaningless. You don't appear to have read the question. -1

Comment: EJP the issue is not usr&pwd or token or certificate the issue is "security". Every user must provide the right credential: it is a bad idea to provide a jar with "blocked" user.

Comment: That's what I said. It isn't a username/password problem. So why is that what your answer is about?

Comment: "Why you want put the usr&pwd into the jaas.conf?"

Comment: He doesn't. Read the question before you comment further. Do you even know what JAAS is? Kerberos?

Comment: "..Now every user can copy the application jar to his local disk, edit jaas.conf, and set his own LoginModule which would allow him to act as different user. .." can you explan me the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: Why? If you don't understand the question you shouldn't be answering it, and if you don't understand how JAAS works you shouldn't be answering the question either. I will just tell you that you don't put usernames and passwords into JAAS configuration files, and that he hasn't mentioned any such thing in his question.

Comment: My question to you: how do you configure the principal of Krb5LoginModule ?

Comment: I don't intend to abuse the comment system by giving you a JAAS tutorial, but JAAS uses callbacks into the application. You are still talking about something that does not appear in the question.